# issues related to the copy of vector with pointer item

Tags: c++, copy, depth

I want to ask whether there are some problems with the copy for the vector of pointer items. Do I need to strcpy or memcpy because there may be depth copy problem?

For instance:

```
Class B;

Class A

{
   ....

private:
   std::vector<B*> bvec;

public:

   void setB(std::vector<B*>& value)

   {

      this->bvec = value;

   }

};

void main()

{

   ....

   std::vector<const B*> value; // and already has values

   A a;

   a.setB(value);

}
```

This example only assign the value to the class variable bvec inside A class. Do I need to use memcpy since I found that std::vector bvec; has pointer items?  I am confused with the depth copy in C++, could you make me clear about that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely you need strcpy or memcpy to solve your problem.  However, I'm not sure what your problem is.

I will try to explain copying as it relates to std::vector.

When you assign bvev to value in setB you are making a deep copy.  This means all of the elements in the vector are copied from value to bvec.  If you have a vector of objects, each object is copied.  If you have a vector of pointers, each pointer is copied.

Another option is to simply copy the pointer *to the vector* if you wish to reference the elements later on.  Just be careful to manage the lifetimes properly!

I hope that helps!

Comment: You mean that the std::vector operator=()  has already solved this depth copy problem in the low-level?

Comment: I mean that "this->bvec = value;" copies every item in the "value" vector individually to the "bvec" vector.  If you are storing pointers however, only the pointers themselves will be copied.  If you wish to copy the objects you'll need to write a loop like this:

`for (std::vector<T*>::iterator i = value.begin; i != value.end; ++i)
{
    this->bvec.insert(*(*i));
}`

where bvec is a std::vector<T>

Comment: Your answer:  "If you wish to copy the objects you'll need to write a loop like this: for (std::vector<T*>::iterator i = value.begin; i != value.end; ++i) { this->bvec.insert(*(*i)); } where bvec is a std::vector<T>"  make me confused again.   I think that in the lower-level std::vector has already solved the deep copy problem since my problem is just copy a vector of pointers to another vector.

Comment: @forester2012 Copying a vector of pointers copies the _pointers_, not the actual objects they point to.

Comment: Now I understand, and if that is the case, I think I can still use these pointers to refer to the actual objects.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this, if you remove and delete an item from the vector `value` *after* you call `setB`, then the vector in `A` will have a pointer that is no longer valid.

So either you need to do a "deep copy", have guarantees that the above scenario will never happen, or use shared smart pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of raw pointers. If you need pointers, I would recommend the last.

There is another alternative, and that is to store the vector in `A` as a reference to the real vector. However, this has other problems, like the real vector needs to be valid through the lifetime of the object. But here too you can use smart pointers, and allocate the vector dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to define your copy constructor for `class A` to ensure the problem your asking about is handled correctly (though not by using `memcpy` or `strcpy`).  Always follow the rule of three here.  I'm pretty sure with `std::vector` your good, but if not, then use a `for` loop instead of `memcpy`